# disable "krunner" temporarily (KDE) while jetbrains tool is running

Tags: ubuntu, kde

i use Jetbrains phpStorm or JetBrains IDEA in Ubuntu and love krunner.
but jetbrains tool use Alt+Space shortcuts.
krunner take that and make jetbrains Alt+Space shortcut not available while krunner runs.

i need probably disable krunner while jetbrains tool is running.

how could i automatic this?

Comment: i love the hotkey, and don't want change it, but you could if you want:  https://askubuntu.com/a/597496/1017209

Comment: as a workaround I have now switched Alt + Space to Meta + Space in global shortcuts (ubuntu). This is very similar and therefore reasonably easy to remember.